# Не подключается прокси Python

Tags: python, proxy, request

Всем привет! В ответ я получаю не IP прокси а свой в чём может быть проблема и как ее решить?

```
import requests

proxies = {'https:': 45.82.179.153:33354}

t2 = requests.get("https://ramziv.com/ip", proxies=proxies).text
print(t2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Вам следует заменить строку
`proxies = {'https:': 45.82.179.153:33354}`
на
`proxies = {'https' : 'https://45.82.179.153:33354', 'http' : 'http://45.82.179.153:33354'}`. Здесь у вас есть 3 ошибки. Первая заключается в том, что вы не заключили строку с прокси в кавычки и не написали протокол. Это вызывает SyntaxError. Вторая в том, что вы забыли про протокол http. А третья в том, что вы поставили двоеточие после https, хотя оно не требуется.